# JSONDecoder extract data from String within a String?

Tags: json, swift, api

XCODE 11.4
SWIFT 5.0

I'm using an API to get a string from JSON. This is my API result:

```
{
  "altimeter": {
    "repr": "3022",
    "spoken": "three zero point two two",
    "value": 30.22
  },
  "clouds": [
    {
      "altitude": 250,
      "modifier": null,
      "repr": "FEW250",
      "type": "FEW"
    }
  ],
  "dewpoint": {
    "repr": "25",
    "spoken": "two five",
    "value": 25
  },
  "flight_rules": "VFR",
  "meta": {
    "timestamp": "Tue, 04 Sep 2018 01:01:47 GMT"
  },
  "other": [],
  "raw": "KJFK 040051Z 20007KT 10SM FEW250 26/25 A3022 RMK AO2 SLP231 T02560250",
  "remarks": "RMK AO2 SLP231 T02560250",
  "remarks_info": {
    "dewpoint_decimal": {
      "repr": "25.0",
      "spoken": "two five point zero",
      "value": 25
    },
    "temperature_decimal": {
      "repr": "25.6",
      "spoken": "two five point six",
      "value": 25.6
    }
  },
  "runway_visibility": [],
  "sanitized": "KJFK 040051Z 20007KT 10SM FEW250 26/25 A3022 RMK AO2 SLP231 T02560250",
  "station": "KJFK",
  "temperature": {
    "repr": "26",
    "spoken": "two six",
    "value": 26
  },
  "time": {
    "dt": "Tue, 04 Sep 2018 00:51:00 GMT",
    "repr": "040051Z"
  },
  "units": {
    "altimeter": "inHg",
    "altitude": "ft",
    "temperature": "C",
    "visibility": "sm",
    "wind_speed": "kt"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "repr": "10",
    "spoken": "one zero",
    "value": 10
  },
  "wind_direction": {
    "repr": "200",
    "spoken": "two zero zero",
    "value": 200
  },
  "wind_gust": null,
  "wind_speed": {
    "repr": "07",
    "spoken": "seven",
    "value": 7
  },
  "wind_variable_direction": []
}
```

I'm able to extract single string information like "raw" and "station", but struggling to extract information within information. For example "Time" -> "retr"

```
struct AeroWX: Decodable {
    var raw: String
    var station: String
}



//button

            let url = URL(string: "https://avwx.rest/api/metar/\(ICAOdep)")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.addValue("xxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in if response != nil
            {
                if let data = data, let body = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                {
                    if body.contains("error")
                    {
                        print(body)
                        self.GlobalTimeStamp = "Invalid ICAO Code"
                        self.doLabelChangeError()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       let user = try! JSONDecoder().decode(AeroWX.self, from: data); DispatchQueue.main.async
                       {
                            print(user.station)
                            print(user.raw)
                       //     print(user.retr)
                            self.GlobalMetar = user.raw
                            self.doLabelChange()
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 print(error ?? "Unknown error")
             }

           }
           task.resume()
        }
        else
        {
            self.GlobalTimeStamp = "Invalid ICAO Code"
            self.doLabelChangeError()
        }
```

Anyone can help, to extract time, retr also rather than just individual strings?

Comment: Please read [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types). And **never** `try!` to decode, `catch` the `error` and `print` it.

Comment: Thanks David, that’s what I tried first, with CodingKeys, but that gave me an error with my URLSession string which I couldn’t fix saying it was void and I couldn’t find a different format that worked with it. Any idea how I can improve my URLSession so it works with the coding keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested structure. Try this:

```
struct AeroWX: Decodable {

    struct Time: Decodable {
        let dt: Date
        let repr: String
    }

    var raw: String
    var station: String
    var time: Time
}
```

You will also need a custom date formatter for the decoder's date decoding strategy. To decode you will need to do this:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
let aero = try decoder.decode(AeroWX.self, from: json)
```

The last thing I should mention is that it's pretty unconventional for the actual timezone abbreviation to be served up on a date field in a json packet. You should talk to your web developer and find out what values you can expect besides 'GMT'. This date formatter will always expect GMT.

Comment: I tried something similar before. And i get a Fatal Error from my JSON Decoding line: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "time", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "dt", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath

Comment: This crashes without an appropriate date decoding strategy. For a beginner I'd recommended to decode just `String`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to run the code. @vadian is correct, the decoder doesn't know how to parse the date. Theres a `dateDecodingStrategy` property on `JSONDecoder`. That needs to be specified. I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: @vadian Give this a shot. I updated my answer with a custom date formatter.

Comment: Will the code not throw back the error now? As my regular json try! Statement through the error without me trying to get these values? And what adjustment would I have to make to retrieve the (retr) part from the nested time structure ?

Comment: @Adamek I tested the decoding part in a playground and I was able to parse raw, station, time.dt, and time.repr just fine. Give it a shot. As for "retr" I'm not sure what you are talking about. There was a "repr" field, but no "retr" field.